# Passing a function with parameters to mapped elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, map-function

The function `changeVideo` is defined like this,

```
  changeVideo(url) {
    alert(url)
  }
```

UI'm trying to pass it to several mapped images.
Here is the function that receives changeVideo and maps it to said images. `videos` is an object. The url ingested by `changeVideo` is a property of the `videos` object.

```
function videoList(videos, changeVideo) {
  return Object.keys(videos).map((key) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          onClick={() => this.changeVideo(videos[key].url)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Finally, here is where I call the `videosList` function, and pass `changeVideo` to it.

```
 <div className="videoList">
      {videoList(this.state.videos, this.changeVideo)}
</div>
```

Somewhere in the process, I'm passing `changeVideo` incorrectly. Thanks for looking!

Comment: `this.changeVideo(videos[key].url)`  -> `changeVideo(videos[key].url)`

Comment: that fixed 'eet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside `videoList` would not have a `changeVideo` property, but since you are already passing it as a function, use `changeVideo` directly:

`this.changeVideo(videos[key].url` changes to `changeVideo(videos[key].url`